# what are design directions in experience design?

Tags: user-experience

Recently I come across a Jargon called '**Design Directions**', I am not sure what exactly it means. can anyone please educate me about Design Direction? & how it add values to experience design? Any resource will be appreciated.

Thanks-

Comment: Where did you come across this jargon?  Links please!

Comment: There is an entire Stack Exchange site, [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), on which this question might be (more) appropriate.  However, it does seem like a very [broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) question to simply ask what a concept is as opposed to something specific about that concept.